# Why not able to run the servlet on Tomcat server?

Tags: java, servlets

I have created the servlet program on the different location of Workspace and after that I created another location of workspace I am getting the error

[image]

But this error doesn't come when I run it on previous workspace location, and also I have closed the previous workspace still getting the error.

Answer (score 5):

As the error **clearly** states, some other program is already listening on those ports.

You can use [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) to find out what.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have launched the project from both the workspaces, who are trying to use the same tomcat instance. So when the second Tomcat instance is launched it encounters port already in use error.